# Operator that combines sum, product and difference between two numbers

Tags: code-golf, number, arithmetic

### Challenge:

There's a silly puzzle circulating on social networks that reads:

```
8 + 2 = 16106
5 + 4 = 2091
9 + 6 = ?
```

Implement a function or operator that, when given two positive integer numbers `x` and `y` such that `x > y > 0`, yields the correct answer as an **integer**, where the answer's digits are the digits of `x * y` followed by the digits of `x + y` followed by the digits of `x - y`. Very simple.

### Rules:

- [Standard loopholes are disallowed.](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest code in bytes wins.
- Input data validation is **not** required. This program may crash or return garbage when given invalid input.
- You're allowed to use numeric functions and operators (including integer and floating point, math library functions, and other functions that accept and return numbers).
- You're allowed to use a function that returns the number of digits of a number, if applicable.
- You're **not** allowed to use strings or any kind of concatenation anywhere in your code.
- The result may be returned or pushed to the stack, whichever applies in the language. The result must be an integer number, not a string.

### Sample code:

**[Dyalog APL](http://tryapl.org/):**

The following code creates a dyadic operator named `X`.

> X←{(⍺-⍵)+((⍺+⍵)×10*1+⌊10⍟⍺-⍵)+⍺×⍵×10*(2+⌊10⍟⍺+⍵)+⌊10⍟⍺-⍵}

Explanation:

- In APL, you evaluate from right to left.
- `⍺ and ⍵` are the left and right operand, respectively
- `⌊10⍟⍺-⍵` reads: `floor of log10(⍺-⍵)`. First performs substraction then logarithm then floor. From right to left. log10 is done in order to count the digits of `⍺-⍵` (you must sum 1 afterwards).
- `⍺×⍵×10*(...)` reads: `10 to the (...)th power, multiplied by ⍵, multiplied by ⍺`
- Hence, `⍺×⍵×10*(2+⌊10⍟⍺+⍵)+⌊10⍟⍺-⍵` is the product, shifted to the left by the sum of the number of digits of the sum and the difference. Multiplying by a power of 10 will shift an integer to the left.
- `((⍺+⍵)×10*1+⌊10⍟⍺-⍵)` is the sum, shifted to the left by the number of digits of the difference.
- `(⍺-⍵)` is the difference. No shifting is necessary here.
- `X←{...}` is how you define an operator in APL.

Examples:

```
      8 X 2
16106
      5 X 4
2091
      9 X 6
54153
```

**GNU dc:**

The following code creates a macro named `a`:

```
[sysx10lxly-dseZdsclxly+dsd+Z1+^lxly**10lc^ld*+le+]sa
```

Explanation:

- `sx` and `sy` pop an element from the stack and save it on the registers `x` and `y`, respectively.
- `lx` and `ly` load an element from registers `x` and `y` respectively and push it to the stack.
- `d` duplicates the last element in the stack.
- `^` computes the power of two numbers.
- `Z` pops a number and returns its number of digits. This is done because `dc` has no logarithm function.
- `[...]sa` stores a macro in register `a`. `la` loads it. `x` executes the macro at the top of the stack.

Examples:

```
8 2 laxn
16106
5 4 laxn
2091
9 6 laxn
54153
```

Comment: I assume conversion from integer to string is invalid?

Comment: I think we've had a challenge much like this but don't know what terms would find the dupe.

Comment: @AnthonyPham "You're not allowed to use strings or any kind of concatenation anywhere in your code."

Comment: Can we take a pair of integers as input?

Comment: Can I make a full program instead of a function?

Comment: @Locoluis - Does appending integer arrays violate your rule against "any kind of concatenation"? What I'm effectively doing is taking one integer array `2 4 8` and appending another `3 5` to create `2 4 8 3 5` in my answer.

Comment: 'No strings or concatenation' is a non-observable rule, as such, it's highly discouraged in a challenge.

Comment: Does `strlen` qualify as "_a function that returns the number of digits of a number_"? There´s an implicit typecast which I cannot avoid; and I doubt that there is any language who has an explicit `count_digits` function. Also, printing a result implies a typecast to string ... So if `strlen` should be banned, printing is at least questionable.

Answer (score 10):

## JavaScript (ES7), <s>63</s> <s>61</s> 59 bytes

Saved 4 bytes thanks to [Neil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/17602/neil).

```
(a,b)=>[a*b,a+b,a-b].reduce((p,c)=>p*10**-~Math.log10(c)+c)
```

```html
<input id=a type=number oninput="c.innerText=((a,b)=>[a*b,a+b,a-b].reduce((p,c)=>p*10**-~Math.log10(c)+c))(+a.value,+b.value)">
<input id=b type=number oninput="c.innerText=((a,b)=>[a*b,a+b,a-b].reduce((p,c)=>p*10**-!Math.log10(c)+c))(+a.value,+b.value)">
<p id=c>
```

Comment: Save a few bytes using `10**-~Math.log10(c)`. (But +1 for using `reduce`, of course.)

Comment: "ES7" Oh, for the love of coding... They're making another one?

Comment: @Feathercrown Yeah, but is it really worse than hearing "Java 9"? Plus it has useful things like `async`/`await` and the exponentiation operator `**`

Comment: @ASCII-only `**` is really useful, I agree. That should've been in ES6.

Answer (score 8):

## C, <s>79</s> 75 bytes

*Thanks to @G B for saving 4 bytes!*

```
#define X for(c=1;(c*=10)<=a
c,d;f(a,b){X+b;);d=c*a*b+a+b;X-b;);a=d*c+a-b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JYjBCsIwEETv@YpQEXaTFayoVGL@Iwcvm6SBHBql9Fb67THVgeHNvHqIY8pllE6m9wzB9gaCsv0Zn5ZFoGgSMHlcnfYGTbRBsfKa23On3bCNKmhue6u5LHLiXADFKmTLZ24qQXeMr/JvRzLBQBfceaPrjw@6Ixqx1S8)

Comment: Save some bytes by using a define instead of a function: https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JYjBCsIwEETv@YpQEXaTFayoVGL@Iwcvm6SBHBql9Fb67THVgeHNvHqIY8pllE6m9wzB9gaCsv0Zn5ZFoGgSMHlcnfYGTbRBsfKa23On3bCNKmhue6u5LHLiXADFKmTLZ24qQXeMr/JvRzLBQBfceaPrjw@6Ixqx1S8

Answer (score 6):

## Bash, 66

- 2 bytes saved thanks to @chepner.

```bash
f()(s=$[$1+$2]
d=$[$1-$2]
echo $[($1*$2*10**${#s}+s)*10**${#d}+d])
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#@5@moalRbKsSrWKorWIUy5UCZuqCmKnJGfkKKtEaKoZaKkZahgZaWirVysW12sWaME5KrXZKrOb/NAULBSOuNAVTBRMgaalg9h8A).

Comment: It is possible to make this almost two times shorter if you place your variables(s, d and the other one for multiplication that you didn't define) next to each other and evaluate that as an arithmetic expression.

Comment: @MaxLawnboy Yes, though that sounds a lot like the banned string concatenation to me.

Comment: Identifier names inside `$[...]` are subject to parameter expansion without the explicit `$` (e.g., `d` instead of `$d`), saving two characters.

Comment: @chepner yep - thanks - I'd missed those.

Comment: Found another two; use `((s=$1+$2,d=$1-$2))` to intialize the two variables.

Answer (score 5):

## EXCEL, 61 Bytes

```
=A1-B1+(A1+B1)*10^LEN(A1-B1)+A1*B1*10^(LEN(A1-B1)+LEN(A1+B1))
```

Excel, 18 Bytes not valid

```
=A1*B1&A1+B1&A1-B1
```

Answer (score 5):

## [Stacked](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/stacked), 36 bytes

```
,@A$(*+-){!A...n!}"!{%y#'10\^x*y+}#\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/stacked#s1Aw@q/j4KiioaWtq1mt6Kinp5enWKukWK1aqaxuaBATV6FVqV2rHPM/v7TkPwA)

Previously: `,@A$(-+*){!A...n!}"!:inits$#'"!$summap:pop@.10\^1\,\*sum`

I'm going to try to squeeze out a byte or two before writing an explanation. (`#'` = size of, and `"` is "do on each", no strings attached here.)

Noncompeting at 26 bytes: `$(*+-)#!!:{%y#'10\^x*y+}#\`.

Answer (score 5):

## TI-Basic, <s>34</s> 33 bytes

```
Prompt A,B
A-B+(A+B)10^(1+int(log(A-B
Ans+AB10^(1+int(log(Ans
```

Comment: I think `Prompt A,B` should also work

Comment: @ConorO'Brien You're right!

Answer (score 4):

## GNU dc, 36

Defines a macro `m` that takes the top two members of the stack, applies the macro and leaves the result on the stack (as per the example in the question):

```
[sadsbla-dZAr^lalb+*+dZAr^lalb**+]sm
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/dc#@x9dnJhSnJSTqJsS5VgUl5OYk6StpQ1na2lpxxbn/rdQMFLIya0o4DJVMIEwLBXMwIz/AA).

Answer (score 3):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org),  <s>81 61</s>  58 bytes

```perl6
->\x,\y{($/=($/=x- y)+(x+y)*({10**$++}...*>$/).tail)+x*y*({10**$++}...*>$/).tail}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#dY7NCoJAHMTv@xR/ZIn9cv2gJBHXHsSLqYGgCa3FLuKTdevFbC06dpjDb2YY5q5beCSyztBgYVePTQv56qvSiNLOBAf5JuODpZwYbikjcxQyhjlfpJRM4YDKqep6yg2z/8JldeOnqdWThhz67tpqQl9PWY/DmQRlwwOaIXQZb7@Sr4BgI7AVuKAwIwBdWfA@FuQKPLE9/VYoWtYjcIjddJREYYIOjvaO4jCNUOogcVC8AQ)

```perl6
->\x,\y{(x*y,x+y,x- y).reduce:{$^a*10**Int(1+log10($^b))+$b}}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#NY7fCoIwHIXv9xQ/ZMTmpm5Soz9o3fYOEqSuCErBWWyIT9ZdL2ar6OJcfIePw7kbDQ8VVxt0czCr2lpDNkV5YXnhBmJDxy3zicDRuNP1vdLrAR@OoRRhuG96Itm1PUtB8KGklOFyHCc/tOu16Q1kcL002hD6esZVeytJUtQsoRuETm33l6IcCLYcO463FAYEYI4Ogm8FWQ4B/7z6KRSN0xIYpH5aKikUWniae0rFSqKVB@Vh@wY)

```perl6
->\x,\y{[[&({$^a*10**Int(1+$^b.log10)+$b})]] x*y,x+y,x- y}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#NY7LCoJAGIX38xQ/MsTcNCdKktDa9gxeQM0iKAcaixnEJ2vXi9lUtDiL7/BxOHfdwiMKmg26Wpg16tBCMvlpbkRuhyybkQGXFZMhY/uuJ5Ljsg4u6iRDynE90qIAw6ww3MUHO05uZde3uteQwOXctZrQ1zNo1LUm8/zA53SD0FHd/pKfAsFGYCvwlsKAAHRlwftWkKTgic@ln0LROK2Bw8JNy0iGEVo5WjpahLFEsYPIwfYN)

Comment: Not knowing Perl 6, I was slightly surprised to discover that `x-y` is a valid identifier.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
+,ạ,.1Fl⁵Ḟ‘€Ṛ+\⁵*
ạ,+,×Fæ.ç
```

Defines a dyadic link / function, callable with `ç`. Takes two integers as input and returns an integer. It has the added bonus of being able to take x`<`y or x`>`y by using absolute difference.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@6@t83DXQh09Q7ecR41bH@6Y96hhxqOmNQ93ztKOAQpocYFktXUOT3c7vEzv8PL/pgqHlyuY/AcA)

Explanation:

```
+,ạ,.1Fl⁵Ḟ‘€Ṛ+\⁵* -- Create link which computes what order of magnitude
                        to multiply the difference, sum, and product by
ạ,+,×Fæ.ç         -- Main link, applies this using dot product
```

Details:

```
+,ạ,.1Fl⁵Ḟ‘€Ṛ+\⁵* -- Create dyadic like which does the following:
       l⁵Ḟ‘       -- Create operation which computes number of digits
                       (log base 10 (⁵ is the literal 10), floored, incremented)
           €      -- Apply this to each element in
+,ạ,.1F           -- ... the list [sum,difference,.1]
            R     -- Reverse the list
             +\   -- Add up first n elements to get list.
               ⁵* -- Raise 10 (⁵ is literal 10) to the power of each element

ạ,+,×Fæ.ç         -- Main link, applies above link
ạ,+,×F            -- The list [difference, sum, product]
      æ.          -- Dot product (multiply corresponding elements) with
        ç         -- The above link.
```

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, <s>79</s> 75 bytes

two versions:

```php
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo(10**strlen($s=$a+$b)*$a*$b+$s)*10**strlen($d=$a-$b)+$d;
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo(10**strlen($a+$b)*$a*$b+$a+$b)*10**strlen($a-$b)+$a-$b;
```

takes input from command line arguments; run with `-r`.

I guess `strlen` qualifies as "function that returns the number of digits",
although it uses the number as a string. Let me know if not.

Comment: 'You're not allowed to use strings or any kind of concatenation anywhere in your code.', so I don't think `strlen` is valid.

Comment: @numbermaniac Let the OP decide. Imo the restriction was to force the solutions to create _one_ result instead of just printing three results after each other. Everything beyond that is nitpicking.

Answer (score 2):

## [C (gcc)](https://gcc.gnu.org/), 70 bytes

```c
#define _ for(c=1;a+b>=(c*=10););d=c*d+a-(b=-b);
c,d;f(a,b){d=a*b;_ _}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#JYzLCsIwEEX3@YqhIsykU7CiooTxS4SQRwNZNEpxV/rtMeqBy4G7OHUXp5TLBBbSc8Ego3G9vwsGLeOBDJkoQcfeDehl8GRU4GgSOva0RnHaGwt2q7m8YXa5IKlVQeO1tCtht4@P8l/HkPDKR/r6zKefb3yhFt3qBw)

based on [Steadybox](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115402/18535) answer, putting everything in a macro to golf it a little more.

(Note: assigning the result to `d` instead of `a` works, unexpectedly. I had a look at the generated assembly code and it seems to be ok.)

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, 54 bytes

```hs
a%0=a
a%b=10*a%div b 10+mod b 10
a#b=(a*b)%(a+b)%(a-b)
```

The puzzle is implemented via an infix function `#`, e.g. `8#2 = 16106`. The other function, `%`, defines base-10 concatenation (assuming the RHS is greater than 0).

Answer (score 2):

## Dyalog APL, 31 bytes

[`{a⊥⍨10*1+⌊10⍟a←(⍺×⍵)(⍺+⍵)(⍺-⍵)}`](http://tryapl.org/?a=f%u2190%7Ba%u22A5%u236810*1+%u230A10%u235Fa%u2190%28%u237A%D7%u2375%29%28%u237A+%u2375%29%28%u237A-%u2375%29%7D%20%u22C4%20f/%A8%288%202%29%285%204%29%289%206%29&run)

based on the sample APL code from the problem statement

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 87 Bytes

```
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo($s=$a-$b)+($t=$a+$b)*10**($l=strlen($s))+$a*$b*10**($l+strlen($t));
```

and a not valid solution for 37 Bytes

```
[,$a,$b]=$argv;echo$a*$b,$a+$b,$a-$b;
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 61 bytes

```
->a,b{[a*b,a+b,a-b].reduce{|x,y|z=y;x*=10while(z>z/=10);x+y}}
```

Which suspiciously looks a lot like [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/115432/18535) Javascript answer, but without using a logarithm.

Answer (score 1):

## R (3.3.1), 104 bytes

```
function(x,y)Reduce(function(p,q)p*10^(floor(log10(q)+1))+q,lapply(c(`*`,`+`,`-`),function(z)z(x,y)),0)
```

returns an anonymous function.

This is my first golfing attempt, so any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I'd say to try to avoid defining functions via the reserved word 'function' if at all possible, it uses up a lot of bytes.  Just do the computation.

Answer (score 1):

## Python, <strike>92</strike> 91 Chars

```
def g(x,y):
    l=lambda x,i=0:l(x/10,i+1)if x else 10**i
    a=x-y
    a+=(x+y)*l(a)
    return x*y*l(a)+a
```

Thanks to Wizards suggestion;)

Comment: Welcome to the site! You don't need the space between `)` and `if`.

Answer (score 0):

### REXX, 70 bytes

```
f:arg a b
c=a-b
c=(a+b)*10**length(c)+c
c=a*b*10**length(c)+c
return c
```

Of course, the native way would be much shorter:

```
f:arg a b
return a*b||a+b||a-b
```

Answer (score 0):

### Python 2.7, <s>109</s> 96 bytes

```
import math
a=lambda n:10**int(math.log10(10*n))
b,c=input()
d=b-c+(b+c)*a(b-c)
print d+b*c*a(d)
```

Corrected after following rules of contest.
Credits to [mbomb007](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/34718/mbomb007) for bringing down the code from 109 bytes to [96 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FctNCoAgEEDhvadwOaMVugkKPMyMQgn@EXZ@s93jgzdibvXpMlO/BblEmQPJclqjVCwdft9SvayBSQVR8OJdLO3tgCI4Xr0G1h4VwWwU7ZmbDJqVnxRwjGPZPw)

Comment: From the rules of this challenge -- `•You're not allowed to use strings or any kind of concatenation anywhere in your code.`

Comment: You can save some bytes by making `a` a lambda. `a=lambda n:10**int(...`. You can also do `b,c=input()`, giving your two inputs separated by a comma.

Comment: @mbomb007 b,c=input() gives TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable. I've tried it.
And the lambda function won't save bytes because I'm calling the function twice in the code. tried that too. :(

Comment: @KoishoreRoy I don't think you get what I mean. [96 bytes](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#FctNCoAgEEDhvadwOaMVugkKPMyMQgn@EXZ@s93jgzdibvXpMlO/BblEmQPJclqjVCwdft9SvayBSQVR8OJdLO3tgCI4Xr0G1h4VwWwU7ZmbDJqVnxRwjGPZPw)

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell, 88 Bytes

```ps
param($x,$y)$l=2;if(($a=$x+$y)-gt9){$l++};($x*$y)*[math]::Pow(10,$l)+$a*10+$x-$y
```

PowerShell does not have a to the power operator which does not help. Also can't count the length of an integer unless you count it as a string, which we can not do, so I check to see if it is `-gt` 9 to get know the length. Likely could be more terse but I have to get back to work.

Answer (score 0):

## [J](http://www.jsoftware.com), 25 bytes

```
X=.10#.[:;10#.inv&.>*;+;-
```

1. `*;+;-` Box the results of each operation.
2. `10#.inv&.>` Convert each result into an array of base-10 digits. (`inv` is `^:_1`)
3. `[:;` Unbox and join the arrays.
4. `10#.` Convert array of base-10 digits into an integer.
5. `X=.` define the above as the operator `X`.

Results:

```
   8 X 2
16106
   5 X 4
2091
   9 X 6
54153
```

Comment: You don't need `X=.`

Comment: @Cyoce - the sample APL code in the challenge defines an operator. I'm pretty sure we're supposed to define a reusable operator for this challenge.

Comment: "3. [:; Unbox and join the arrays." - "You're not allowed to use strings or any kind of concatenation anywhere in your code."

Comment: @ngn - Please expand on your comment. At no point are strings used.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that "join" ("link"?) might constitute a "kind of concatenation", though I'm not very familiar with J, and I'm not sure how to interpret the problem statement in this case. My own solution raises similar questions - I use stranding (juxtaposition of nouns in APL forms a vector) which might be the same as J's "link" but without a glyph to represent it.

Comment: Ahh. Interesting read of "any kind of concatenation." I suppose we should ask the challenge creator. What I'm effectively doing is taking one integer array `2 4 8` and appending another `3 5` to create `2 4 8 3 5`.

Comment: Any reason you use`^:_1` in your solution but`inv` in your explanation?

Comment: Typo. I messed up somewhere in my edits. 25 bytes is a count with `inv`.

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 67 bytes

```
c=Ceiling;l=Log10;#-#2+(#+#2)10^(c@l[#-#2]/. 0->1)+10^c@l[2#]10#2#&
```

Takes `x-y`, then takes the log10 of `x-y`, rounds it up, calculates 10 to the power of that and then multiplies it by `x+y`. But we also need to consider `log10(x-y)` being 0, so we replace 0 with 1. Then we take the log10 of `2x`, rounded up, plus 1, and find 10 to the power of that. Multiply that by `xy`, and add that on.

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>23</s> <s>22</s> 16 bytes

```
-Dg°¹²+*Dg°¹²**O
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@6/rkn5ow6GdhzZpa8FYWlr@//@bcVkCAA)

We could have saved a few bytes if we'd been allowed to use strings in the program (but not in calculations) by looping over a string containing the operations `"-+*"`, as the code performed for each operation is the same.
Of course, if we'd been allowed to use concatenation we'd saved a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

### R, 64 bytes

```
x=scan();(b=(a=diff(-x))+10^nchar(a)*sum(x))+10^nchar(b)*prod(x)
```

Usage:

```
> x=scan();(b=(a=diff(-x))+10^nchar(a)*sum(x))+10^nchar(b)*prod(x)
1: 8 2
3: 
Read 2 items
[1] 16106
```